# Problemas com PHP e Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Eu estava montando essa api em php ligado com o xampp seguindo esse video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ou1ERM2MOw&index=4&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjQaV062aE_CW68xgXdYFpV), mas mesmo eu seguindo exatamente o video eu não consigo fazer funcionar aqui... quando eu faço o teste no postMan ele acusa erro, será que algum sabe oq acontece e pode me ajudar.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda...

---

### Erro

```
Notice: Undefined index: RESQUEST_METHOD in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\v1\registerUser.php on line 8
{"error":true,"message":"Erro no request 404"}
```

---

### registerUser

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['RESQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(
    isset($_POST['username']) and
        isset($_POST['password']) and
            isset($_POST['email'])
    ){

        $db = new DbOperations();

        if($db->createUsuario(
            $_POST['username'],
            $_POST['password'],
            $_POST['email']))
        {
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "Usuario Registrado com sucesso";
        }
        else
        {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Desculpe ocorreu um erro";
        }
}   
else
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Required falha";
}
else
{
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = "Erro no request 404";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

---

### DbOperations

```
<?php

class DBOperations{

    private $con;

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }

    /*CRUD-> C-> Create */

    function createUsuario($username,$senha,$email){

        $password = md5($pass);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$senha,$email);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}   

?>
```

---

### DbConnect

```
<?php

class DbConnect{

        private $con;

        function __construct(){

        }

        function connect(){
            include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/
                Constants.php';
            $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);    
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "Erro ao conectar ao database".mysqli_connect_err();
            }   

            return $this->con;
        }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teu problema não é com Xampp, você escreveu o nome da variável errado, `RESQUEST_METHOD` não existe, o correto é `REQUEST_METHOD`, assim:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
```

Veja na própria documentação do PHP como se escreve os nomes https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, já vi a cagada que eu fiz...

Comment: @MatheusRodrigues se a resposta lhe resolveu o problema por favor marque-a como correta.